# ManipulationCompleted is not firing on eventtocommand (mvvm ligt) when i try to bind slider

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I tried to bind slider event ManipluationCompleted  using EventTocommand but its not getting fired but ManipluationStarted  works fine is there any way to solve thsi

My xaml code:

```
 <Slider x:Name="Choice_Slider" Grid.Row="2" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="50" Foreground="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}"   >
            <Slider.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/sliderbar.png"/>
            </Slider.Background>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationCompleted">
                    <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SliderStartedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>

            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Slider>
```

In the ViewModel i used the following code :

```
 public RelayCommand<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs> SliderStartedCommand 
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

The relaycommand :

```
 SliderStartedCommand = new RelayCommand<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>((e) => OnSliderMovedDelta(e));
```

The OnSliderMovedDelta function:

```
private void  OnSliderMovedDelta(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {


            //var Sliderparam = e.
            //var xvalue = Sliderparam.X;

        }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Don't really know if it's like `Storyboard.Completed`, since that implementation is not as straightforward as you'd like, exactly like you did for `ManipulationCompleted`.

Comment: Have you tried to handle the `ManipulationCompleted` event in the code behind and see if it fires or not ??! Also try to set the RelayCommand in the get method of the `SliderStartedCommand` property